# Are the vectors $u_1 \times u_2$ and $u_1 \times u_3$ linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'll try  to show that if the vectors $u_1, u_2$ and $u_3$ are linearly dependent, then, $u_1 \times u_2$ and $u_1 \times u_3$ are also linearly dependent.

I'm thinking like this. If we can show that $u_1 \times u_3$ and $u_1 \times u_2$ are parallell to one another, that way, we can deduce that they're linearly dependent.

The dot product yields:

$v = (u_1 \times u_2) \cdot (u_1 \times u_3)$

Now, using that they're linearly dependent, we can, without loss of generality, say that $u_3$ is a linear combination of $u_1$ and $u_2$, hence linearly dependent.

$(u_1 \times u_2) \cdot (u_1 \times (\lambda_1 u_1 + \lambda_2 u_2))$

For some $\lambda_j \neq 0$.

Further, we get:

$(u_1 \times u_2) \cdot (\lambda_1 u_1 \times u_1 +  u_1 \times \lambda_2 u_2))$

Using the fact that the cross product between two equal vectors is 0, we simplify even further to get:

$\lambda_2(u_1 \times u_2) \cdot (u_1 \times u_2)$

Now, how can I go on with this? I'm thinking that there might be an even easier way to do this.

Thank you for any tips.

Comment: you can read the desired result directly off from your calculations. Ignore the dot product.

Comment: Hint: if $au_1+bu_2+cu_3=0$ with $a,\,b,\,c$ not all $0$ then $u_1\times$ gives...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u_1$, $u_2$ and $u_3$ are linearly dependent then there exist scalars $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ (not all zero) such that
$$c_1u_1+c_2u_2+c_3u_3=0.$$
Of course $u_1\times u_1=0$, and $c_2$ and $c_3$ are not both zero (assuming that $u_1\neq0$), so it follows that
\begin{eqnarray*}
c_2(u_1\times u_2)+c_3(u_1\times u_3)
&=&c_1(u_1\times u_1)+c_2(u_1\times u_2)+c_3(u_1\times u_3)\\
&=&u_1\times(c_1u_1+c_2u_2+c_3u_3)\\
&=&u_1\times0\\
&=&0,
\end{eqnarray*}
which shows that $u_1\times u_2$ and $u_1\times u_3$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: Thanks, that was clear for me :)